# How can I add a inner North panel using jQuery Layout UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, layout

I came a cross a page management plugin i.e. [jQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/demos.cfm). I want to use it in an application I am developing.

I am trying to create a page that have 3 panels. On the west, I need to add a panel that takes the full height of my page. I also need to add a north panel that will start from where the "west panel" end, all the way to the east side of the screen. Finally, I like to add a panel in the middle "under the west panel which take the remaining of the page.

In other words, I am trying to do the following layout using [jQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/demos.cfm).

[image]

Here is what I have done

```js
 $(function () {
  $('body').layout({
   applyDefaultStyles: true,
   west__size: 200
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://layout.jquery-dev.com/lib/js/jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>

<link href="http://layout.jquery-dev.com/lib/css/layout-default-latest.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui-layout-north ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-north">
  NORTH
 </div>
 <div class="ui-layout-west">
  WEST
 </div>
 <div class="ui-layout-center">
  MIDDLE
 </div>
```

But, this is making the north panel go across the page and over the west panel.

How can I fix it and get the look that I drew above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. To do this, I have to give a new ID to the center div and create a new instance of `layout` so I have 2 separate instances one inside the other

this did the trick

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#mainContainer').layout({
            applyDefaultStyles: true,
            west__size: 300
        });

        $('#innderContainer').layout({
            applyDefaultStyles: true
        });

    });
</script>

<div id="mainContainer" class="ui-layout-center">

    <div class="ui-layout-west">
        West
    </div>

    <div class="ui-layout-center" id="innderContainer">

        <div class="ui-layout-pane-south">
            SOUTH
        </div>

        <div class="ui-layout-north">
            North
        </div>

        <div id="centerInnerCenterPane" class="ui-layout-center">
            Center
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You sort of answered your own question when you asked about an "inner north pane". What you need is an outer layout containing only west and center panes. Then inside that center-pane you add an inner-layout with only north and center panes. That will give you what you want...

```
<div class="ui-layout-west"> WEST </div>
<div class="ui-layout-center">
    <div class="ui-layout-north"> NORTH </div>
    <div class="ui-layout-center"> CENTER </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The code you provided id not work. It showed the west panel all the way to the top. but the north panel is not there any more.

Comment: Should there be a different class name for the inner panes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you also need to *init* the inner layout. I didn't show that code before because I thought you knew. However there are many ways of doing so that don't require adding element ID's, such as...

1. Layout accepts *any* jQuery selector, so you could do this:

   ```
   $('body').layout({
       applyDemoStyles: true,
       west__size: 300
   });

   $('body > .ui-layout-center').layout({
       applyDemoStyles: true
   });
   ```
2. Or you can access the outer layout pane through the layout object returned:

   ```
   // change the global default to avoid repeating
   $.layout.defaults.panes.applyDemoStyles = true;

   $('body').layout({
       west__size: 300
   }).panes.center.layout();
   ```
3. Or use the "children" option to specify a nested layout:

   ```
   $('body').layout({
       applyDemoStyles: true,
       west__size: 300,
       center__children: {
           applyDemoStyles: true,
           north__size: 150
       }
   });
   ```

There are even more ways, such as adding layout options as a data-layout attribute on the container element; but the examples above are enough!

I recommend asking Layout questions in the dedicated forum. You'll likely get quicker answers and your question may help others with similar scenarios.